# How to call only one button click function when user press enter from Textbox in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

> I already made my code. But when user enter the `EnterKey`, it is calling 2 button event on server side. I want to call only one event.

I have three Asp.net buttons,

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" class="btn btn-info" runat="server" Text="SEARCH" Width="100" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveFile" runat="server" Text="SaveFile" OnClick="btnSaveFile_Click"/>
<asp:Button ID="btnLoadData" CssClass="btn btn-info"  runat="server" Text="Ok" OnClick="btnLoadData_Click" />
```

> Those 3 buttons will perform 3 different things. I have a textbox, once user enter the data and when they press the enter I want to call the `btnSaveFile` click event.

This is that text box

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFileName" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Note**

> I already define the **click function for btnSaveFile** here is the code

```
$('#btnSaveFile').click(function () {
    var fileNames = $('#txtFileName').val();
    var flag = 'returnTrue';
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ReportTotalSalesPivot.aspx/getFileExistOrNot',
        method: 'post',
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: '{fileName:"' + fileNames + '",reportName:"TotalSales"}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d === 'dataExist') {
                flag = 'returnFalse';
                $('#lblSaveErrorMsg').text('This filename already exist. Please change the name');
            }
            else {
                //alert('else');
                $(".FilterTable > tbody > tr").each(function () {
                    $("#hiddenTableRecord").val($("#hiddenTableRecord").val() + $(this).find(".FieldNameID").html() + "$$$" + $(this).find(".OperatorID").html() + "$$$");
                });
                $("#hiddenTableRecord").val('');
                return true;
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('Please Call Administrator');
        }
    });
    //alert('faisal'+flag);
    if (flag === 'returnFalse') {
        return false;
    }

});
```

The below code is for to call the above function.

```
$('#txtFileName').keydown(function (e) {
    //enter key
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 13) {
        $('#btnSaveFile').click();
        return false;
    }
})
```

**Problem**

> **keydown function** is working fine. But at the same time when I press the enter key **it is calling `btnSearch` server side code also. It should not call** `btnSearch`. It should call `btnSaveFile` on server side

**Doubt**

> Totally I have 3 server side button, But it is calling only 2 why? (Just want to know the reason). Target: want to call only one button

Thanks

Comment: Can you inspect the code using any DevTool like Chrome inspect.

Comment: use the attribute UseSubmitBehaviour="false" like `<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="just a button" />`

Comment: @RonyLoud What is the use of `UseSubmitBehavior="false"`?. So this button will not execute any more when user press the enter key?

Comment: [UseSubmitBehavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

however i would suggest put your button and textbox into update panel and then set default button on update panel. 
like below:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSearch">     
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
    <ContentTemplate> 
        <input runat="server" id="txtSearch" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search the Store..." /> 
        <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" class="btn btn-info" runat="server" Text="SEARCH" Width="100" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" /> 
    </ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel> 
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: you would have asked in comments.

Comment: don't have much reputation point to add comments on your question.

Comment: however i would suggest
put your button and textbox into update panel and then set default button on update panel. like below:
      <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSearch">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
       <ContentTemplate>
<input runat="server" id="txtSearch" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search the Store..." />
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" class="btn btn-info" runat="server" Text="SEARCH" Width="100" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
</ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
    </asp:Panel>

Comment: let me know either it works for you or no. in this code no need to add Jquery code specifically for enter button..update panel will do by self

Comment: This is not exact answer, any how it is helpful to find the solution. Now I got it. thanks. I have edited your answer, please approve it.

Comment: welcome. i know but it resolved the issue however if you found some good thing plz share it .